# Question about Lagrangian Multiplier

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The question is $\max_{x,y} x^{2}+y^{2}$ subject to $x^{2}+xy+y^{2}-4 = 0$.

First, I set up the Lagrangian:

$L =x^{2}+y^{2}-\lambda (x^{2}+xy+y^{2}-4)$

Then, I calculated the first order condition:

$L_{x}^{'}=2x-(2x+y)\lambda=0 $

$L_{y}^{'}=2y-(2y+x)\lambda=0 $

$L_{\lambda}^{'}=x^{2}+xy+y^{2}-4=0 $

I don't know how to get $(x, y, \lambda)$ from these three conditions. Can someone teach me?

(When I check the solution, it says that from the first two conditions we can get $x^{2}=y^{2}$, I am confused by this statement.)

Comment: Yes, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

write the first equations in the form
$$2x=(2x+y)\lambda$$
$$2y=(2y+x)\lambda$$
dividing both equation by each other we have
$$\frac{x}{y}=\frac{2x+y}{2y+x}$$ solve this for $x$ or $y$
simplifying this we get $$x^2-y^2=0$$ or $$(x-y)(x+y)=0$$

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The first two equations can be written as 
$$2x(1-\lambda)=\lambda y, \ \ \ 2y(1-\lambda)=\lambda x.$$

The third equation tells you that $x,y$ cannot be both zero. If $\lambda=1$, we would get $x=y=0$, so now we know that $\lambda\ne1$. Similarly, $x=0$ implies $y=0$ and viceversa. Now, knowing that both $x,y\ne0$, 
$$
\frac{2x}y=\frac\lambda{1-\lambda}=\frac{2y}x.
$$
We deduce that $2x^2=2y^2$, so $x^2=y^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Or rewrite first like $\frac{2-2\lambda }{\lambda}  \times x =y$
and substitute $y$ by left part in the second equation

you will get the quadratic equation for lambda
Solving it you will get two equation $x = y$, and $x = -y$

you can choose one trying each in the third equation.